# No exported member

Tags: angular

From `app/graph-options/options.ts`, I'm exporting a variable:

```
export let lineChartLevel2: string = "EXPORT";
```

From `app/level-2/level-2.component.ts`, I'm importing the variable:

```
import { lineChartLevel2 } from '../graph-options/options';
```

This results in the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

c:/PDWS/src/app/level-2/level-2.component.ts (6,10): 
Module '"c:/PDWS/src/app/graph-options/options"' has no exported member 'lineChartLevel2'.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export) you cannot export a local variable

Use `const` to export a simple string, number etc

```
export const lineChartLevel2: string = "EXPORT";
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working now, and I'm actually exporting an object. The template says that the imported object is undefined, but when I print it to the console, it's fine. Do you know why?

Comment: how are you importing and in which file this `exported object is present`?

Comment: I'm importing it the same way as I've written in my question. It's present in my component, level-2.component.ts.

Comment: you cannot keep these constant objects inside the component and access outside because the component might not be instantiated.

Comment: I solved it by creating a variable in my component and then in `ngOnInit()` I assigned the imported constant to the component variable. Thanks for your help.

Comment: should we use service instead of constant?